# exec xp_cmdshell bcp syntax

Tags: sql-server, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I can't seem to find the right syntax to export data with column names using exec xp_cmdshell bcp in sql server management studio.I've tried the below variations

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell bcp "select "a_id","b_id","c_id" union select a_id,b_id,c_id from  tablename out 
"\\network_path\a.txt" -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sservername"
```

And

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell bcp 'select 'a_id','b_id','c_id' union select a_id,b_id,c_id from  tablename out 
'\\network_path\a.txt' -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sservername'
```

And

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell bcp 'select "a_id","b_id","c_id" union select a_id,b_id,c_id from  tablename out 
"\\network_path\a.txt" -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sservername'
```

And

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell bcp "select 'a_id','b_id','c_id' union select a_id,b_id,c_id from  tablename out 
'\\network_path\a.txt' -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sservername"
```

I have successfully used the below command to export the table,however I also need the column names.

```
bcp tablename out "\\network_path\a_test.txt" -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sservername'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you'll actually need to order the header row so it appears on top.  This should handle it

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from (select ''a_id'' as a_id,''b_id'' as b_id,''c_id'' as c_id union select a_id,b_id,c_id from tablename)q order by case a_id when ''a_id'' then 0 ELSE 1 END" queryout "\\networkpath\a.txt" -c -Uusername -Ppassword -Sservername -ddatabasename'
```

Comment: usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile  [-m maxerrors] [-f formatfile] [-e errfile]  [-F firstrow] [-L lastrow]  [-b batchsize]  [-n native type] [-c character type] [-w wide character type] [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier] [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]  [-i inputfile] [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]  [-S server name]  [-U username] [-P password]  [-T trusted connection] [-v version]  [-R regional enable]  [-k keep null values] [-E keep identity values]  [-h "load hints"]